# how to set the default Icons set on every page for AddThis

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addthis

I would like to modify the code so it will display atleast 10 icons when the page loads.
how could I do this on addThis?
Thanks

Comment: what exactly you want. Try to be more specifc and show us some of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style "></div>
```

jQuery:

```
var totalButtons = 10;
for(var i=1;i<=totalButtons;i++){
   $('.addthis_toolbox').append('<a class="addthis_button_preferred_'+i+'"></a>');
}
```

Please post any code you are currently using for your AddThis widget.